# How can we handle headphone play/pause button events in foreground in ios

Tags: objective-c, iphone-5, ios6.1, uievent

I have an requirement that to handle headphone play/pause button events in foreground. How ever I am able to handle the same scenario in background using the below code

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents)]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"Responds!");
}
```

Please help with an explanation or sample code if possible. I have done lots of research but no help.

Answer (score 13):

There is another way to implement player control from headphones.
use `MPRemoteCommandCenter` tooglePlayPauseCommand.
[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPRemoteCommandCenter_Ref/)

```
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].togglePlayPauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(onTooglePlayPause)];
```

Answer (score 12):

You must check  this criteria:

1. Edit your info.plist to stipulate that you do audio (UIBackgroundModes) in the background as well as foreground.
2. Implement this function:

   ```
   - (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)theEvent 
   {
     if (theEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl)
     {
       switch(theEvent.subtype) {
       case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
               //Insert code
               break;
           case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
               //Insert code
               break;
           case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
               // Insert code
               break;
           case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:
               //Insert code.
               break;
           default:
               return;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

...obviously, replace the "//insert code" with whatever functionality is relevent in your app.

3>Finally, in order for that above function to be called, insert this in your viewDidAppear event:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    if ([self canBecomeFirstResponder]) {
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```

also please see this link:
http://www.sagorin.org/2011/11/29/ios-playing-audio-in-background-audio/

Comment: thanks for your reply, however I am able to handle the events in background also I have added the UIBackgroundModes in plist but I have no idea about foreground events handling. I have tried trigging the mentioned method '- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)theEvent ' but no luck. Can you please explain me how can we add foreground keys in plist.

Comment: After 2 min, if press on headphone button, Music app started and play previous sound.

Answer (score 4):

The swift 2 version for slobodans solution:

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter().togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(togglePlayStop(_:)));
```